# Illegal exception zip file is closed in apache poi for docx file creating after build as jar

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

Am creating docx file using poi and its supporting jars. It is working fine in my IDE but when I build as jar it is not working. It throws the below error

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException:     
      Zip File is closed at          org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getEntries(ZipFil    eZipEntrySource.java:45) at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java: 182) 
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:226)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:67)
```

Comment: Which version of POI jar you are using?

Comment: POI 3.10. It works in netbeans IDE but it failed while running as jar

Comment: How are you triggering this?